# get the inverse of a php matrix from python file

Tags: php, python

PHP code:

```
<?php
$arr=array(array('1','2','3','4'),array('21','12','23','54'),array('10','23','35','41'),array('14','62','93','40'));
$result = shell_exec("C:/Python27/python 123.py ".json_encode($arr));
echo $result;
?>
```

python code:

```
import sys, json
arr=sys.argv[1]
print arr
A=np.matrix(arr)
print A
print ("<br/>")
M=A.I
print M
result = {'Name':'abc'}
print ("Sending data to PHP")
print (json.dumps(result))
```

The output given as inverse is not coming correct plus the A matrix is coming out to be of dimenesion 1x16 instead of 4x4 and the dimension of array arr is correct(4x4).How to debug it and get correct matrices A and M?

Comment: Not a python coder, but seems to me that you're not decoding the json string you're passing in as a command line argument. `arr` would start out as a string, which you then feed into the matrix operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem not to be decoding the JSON within the Python script, whilst `json_encode($arr)` should be `json_decode($arr)` unless I'm wrong.

Comment: No, bcoz json_decode expects a string as parameter while $arr is an array

Comment: I think I got it.. I shud use json.loads(sys.argv[1])